# -ridden vs -laden (adjective usage)

Tags: adjectives

Usage of:

> Scandal-**ridden** companies, disease-**ridden** countries, etc.

Vs.

> Debt-**laden** banks, cynism-**laden** mindset

In terms of -**laden** and -**ridden** context, both have the same meaning, which is ''*full of*'' something. However, I can't choose which is more appropriate to use accordingly. Are there patterns in how to use them?

Comment: Edit suggestion: ladden ==> laden.

Comment: The latter is _-laden_ not _-ladden_. And that is neutral, whereas _-ridden_ always has a bad connotation.

Comment: @ColinFine IMO **laden** is not neutral. It suggests a burden, as shown by OP's examples.

Comment: A burden, perhaps, @WeatherVane, but not necessarily something bad. Consider _an emotion-laden voice_, and _a star laden team_ (both of which I just found in the NOW corpus).

Comment: @ColinFine I don't see how a "star laden team" is neutral, or even good, but in suggesting that it is good or bad, do you agree that it is not neutral? Since when is a burden good, unless on a spiritual quest which might make it ultimately so?

Comment: @WeatherVane: What I am suggesting is that in the phrase _X-ridden_, the implication is always that X is something the speaker regards as bad. In the phrase _X-laden_ that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @ColinFine I agree with that, but not in the **laden** examples given here, which suggest negativity.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I agree that _-laden_ can be used negatively; I'm saying that it is not always (if you're saying that the examples I gave are negative, I don't agree).

Comment: @ColinFine not at all, I meant the ones in the question.

Answer (score 3):

[**Ridden**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ridden):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : harassed, oppressed, or obsessed by —usually used in combination · guilt-*ridden* · debt-*ridden*
>
> **2** : excessively full of or supplied with —usually used in combination ·     slum-*ridden*

The first sense of **ridden** is negative, while the second sense simply means *excessively* full.

[**Laden**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laden):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : carrying a load or burden

This word only has a single sense given, and it doesn't have the same necessarily implication of excessiveness.

**Laden**, when used as a compound adjective, *can* be associated with negative things, but it's meant more as an intensifier than a negative in its own right.

For example:

> At that time, the high-priced, veteran-*laden* Tigers saw the writing on the wall.

There is little negative about veterans, so it just means that there are a lot of them.

Or, to make up some sentences of my own:

> It was a promise-laden job.
>   The child had hope-laden dreams.

Unlike **ridden**, **laden** is also used in a different, and more neutral way when not combined into a compound adjective:

> heavily *ladened* with equipment
>   *laden* a ship with emergency medical supplies
>   The truck was *laden* with gravel.